# How can i validate OnActionExecuting methode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How can I cross-check if, when my *OnActionExecuting*  returns *True*, it allows me to execute the controller method, otherwise it denies it?

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            if (2 ==2)
            {
               // throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
                return (new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
                return;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to set the actionContext.Result property before you leave the handler. Something like this:

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        // Adjust this if statement so it's executed hit if your special authentication has *failed*
        if (true)
        {
            actionContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You don't have access to this resource.");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

If you don't do anything in the handler, the controller action will execute as normal.

Comment: actionContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You don't have access to this resource.");
        }
   is not workinfg

Comment: Is the action filter actually being executed? You need to decorate your controller action with it, or add it globally in FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters (in the App_Start folder) like so `filters.Add(new SessionExpireAttribute())`.